# Отличить текст от ссылки

Tags: jquery

Есть форма ввода YouTube. В неё можно ввести поисковой запрос или вставить ссылку на видео YouTube. Как понять что именно было введено в форму для составления дальнейшего условия?

P.s: ссылки могут быть только такого типа **`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yre6iXvnONc`**

```
<input type="text" name="create--post--youtube">
<small>Введите название или вставьте ссылку видео YouTube</small>

<script>
$('input[name=create--post--youtube]').change(function(){
   var value = $(this).val();

   if (...) {
      console.info('Введён поисковой запрос');
   } else {
      console.info('Введена ссылка на видео YouTube');
   }
});
</script>
```

Comment: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=*` - значит ссылка, всё остальное - строка поиска

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Символ | означает 'или'... т.е. тут `(|s)` записано ' ничего или "s" '

```js
$('#moo').change(function(){
  var val = $(this).val();
  if ( val.match(/http(|s):\/\/www.youtube.com/gi) ) {
    $('#demo').html('Введена ссылка на видео YouTube');
  } else if ( val.match(/http/gi) ){
    $('#demo').html('Внешняя ссылка!');
  } else {
    $('#demo').html('Введён поисковый запрос');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="moo" type="text" name="create--post--youtube">
<div>Введите название или вставьте ссылку видео YouTube</div>

<p id="demo"></p>
```